# FreeRADIUS authorization

Tags: cisco, authentication, freeradius

We currently have FreeRADIUS to either forward or drop requests (to authentication server) based on the AV pairs received during client authentication (shown below).  However what I would like to do is rather than drop those requests that do not have the appropriate AV pairs I would like to forward the request for authentication but drop any 'access-accept' message that is returned and generate an email.

```
authorize {
    # Check for a specific value in Cisco-AVPair attribute
    if (&Cisco-AVPair[1] =~ /mdm-tlv=device-mac=xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx/) 
    {
        ok
    }
    else {
        reject
    }
```